# Local cohomology and residues of rational functions at 0 and $\infty$

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Let $a_1,\dots,a_s$ and $b_1,\dots,b_t$ be positive integers, where
$s,t>0$. Choose $c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $M_c$ be the real vector
space spanned by all monomials $x^\alpha y^\beta=x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots
x_s^{\alpha_s}y_1^{\beta_1}\cdots y_t^{\beta_t}$ such that each
$\alpha_i,\beta_j\geq 0$ and $\sum a_i\alpha_i-\sum b_j\beta_j=c$. Let
$R$ be the same except $\sum a_i\alpha_i-\sum b_j\beta_j=0$. Then $R$
is a finitely-generated $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and $M_c$ is a
finitely-generated $R$-module, both of Krull dimension $d=s+t-1$.
Let $0\leq i<d$, and let
$H^i(M_c)$ denote the $i$th local cohomology module of $M_c$ (with
respect to the irrelevant maximal ideal of $R$, i.e, the ideal spanned
by all monomials $x^\alpha y^\beta\in R$ except for $x^\alpha
y^\beta=1$). Let $E_c$ be the set of all integer vectors $(\alpha,\beta)$
such that $\sum a_i\alpha_i-\sum b_j\beta_j=c$. If
$\gamma=(\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_k)$, let $\gamma>0$ mean that each
$\gamma_i>0$, and similarly $\gamma\geq 0$, etc.

According to Theorem 3.3 of 
[this reference](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/51.pdf), the multigraded Hilbert series $F(H^i(M_c),x,y)$ in the
variables $(x,y)=(x_1,\dots,x_s,y_1,\dots,y_t)$ is given by
$$ F(H^s(M_c),x,y) =
    \sum_{{(\alpha,\beta)\in E_c}\atop
  {\alpha<0,\ \beta\geq 0}}
   x^\alpha y^\beta,\ \mathrm{if}\ c<0 $$
$$ F(H^t(M_c),x,y) =
    \sum_{{(\alpha,\beta)\in E_c}\atop
  {\alpha\geq 0,\ \beta< 0}}
   x^\alpha y^\beta,\ \mathrm{if}\ c>0 $$
and otherwise $H^i(M_c)=0$ for $i<d$.

Now consider the rational function
$$ H(z) = \frac{z^{-c}}{(1-z^{a_1}x_1)\cdots(1-z^{a_s}x_s)
  (1-z^{-b_1}y_1)\cdots (1-z^{-b_t}y_t)}. $$
Note that if we formally expand $H(z)$ into a Laurent series in $z$ in
the obvious way, then the constant term (the term independent from
$z$) is just the multigraded Hilbert series $F(M_c,x,y)$ of $M_c$, which in this
case is just the sum of all monomials $x^\alpha y^\beta$ in $M_c$. If
we let each $x_i$ and $y_j$ be a small (in absolute value) complex
number, then by the Cauchy integral theorem,
$$ F(M_c,x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint H(z)\frac{dz}{z}, $$
where the contour of integration is the unit circle $|z|=1$. We can
evaluate this integral by the residue theorem. Of interest here are
the residues at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$. One can compute that
$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{H(z)}{z} =
   (-1)^{s+t} F(H^t(M_c),x,y),\ \mathrm{if}\ c>0 $$

$$ \mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} \frac{H(z)}{z} =
   (-1)^{s-1} F(H^s(M_c),x,y),\ \mathrm{if}\ c<0. $$
Is there a reason for this connection between residues and local
cohomology? I know that there is a big literature on ``residues and
duality'' and related topics, but I don't understand it well enough to
see whether it answers my question.

We can generalize to linear equations in more than one variable. (The
single linear equation related to the discussion above is $\sum
a_i\alpha_i-\sum b_j\beta_j=c$.) If there are $k$ equations, then
$H(z)$ is replaced with a rational function of $k$ variables
$z_1,\dots,z_k$. For instance, if the equations are
$x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4-2x_5=1$ and $3x_1-x_2+x_3+2x_4-x_5=-2$, then
$$ H(z_1,z_2) = \frac{z_1^{-1}z_2^2}{D}, $$
where
$$ D=(1-z_1z_2^3x_1)(1-z_1z_2^{-1}x_2)
  (1-z_1^{-1}z_2x_3)(1-z_1^{-1}z_2^2x_4)
 (1-z_1^{-2}z_2^{-1}x_5). $$
We can find the term of $H(z_1,z_2)/z_1z_2$ independent from $z_1$ and
$z_2$ by a process of iterated contour integration, as explained in
Section 9 of [this
reference](https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/22.pdf). Some examples show that there is a connection
between the residues at 0 and $\infty$ of the rational functions
encountered in this process, and the local cohomology of the
corresponding module. I don't know what the precise statement should
be. As a very special case, it seems to be the case that if we never
encounter nonzero residues at 0 or $\infty$, then the corresponding
module is Cohen-Macaulay. The Cohen-Macaulay property is equivalent to
$H^i(M_c)=0$ except for $i=\dim M_c$. Here $c=(c_1,\dots,c_k)$ (the
constant terms of the equations), and $\dim$ denotes Krull dimension.